# sendmail / postfix in laravel homestead vagrant

Tags: ubuntu, laravel, vagrant, sendmail, postfix-mta

I have a laravel-homestead box.
I installed mailutils by
"apt-get install mailutils"
It then asked me to configure postfix I choose "Internet.." option.
When I try to send an email by running

`echo "Test" | mail -s "testing email" myemail@gmail.com`

I don't receive any email.

> /var/log/mail.log:

```
Nov  7 22:28:43 homestead postfix/master[1553]: reload -- version 2.11.0, configuration /etc/postfix
Nov  7 22:29:13 homestead postfix/pickup[2289]: 1364660ECE: uid=0 from=<root@homestead>
Nov  7 22:29:13 homestead postfix/cleanup[2299]: 1364660ECE: message-id=<20141107222913.1364660ECE@homestead>
Nov  7 22:29:13 homestead postfix/qmgr[2290]: 1364660ECE: from=<root@homestead>, size=331, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov  7 22:29:43 homestead postfix/smtp[2301]: connect to gmail.com[74.125.230.149]:25: Connection timed out
```

I am fairly newbie when it comes to linux machines. I have been trying to make sendmail work with laravel-homestead vagrant virtual machine with no luck.

Has anyone else experienced this?

Many thanks.